# Getting 'Unknown Interaction' error when creating new giveaway inteaction in discord.py

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

I am trying to create discord giveaway bot with discord.py. This is my interaction function for creating the giveaway:

```
    @app_commands.command(name="startgive", description="starts a giveaway")
    @app_commands.describe(
        duration="duration of the giveaway", 
        winners="number of winners",
        prize="the prize being given away",
    )
    async def startgive(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, duration: str, winners: int, prize: str):
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
            try:
                if (winners <= 0):
                    await interaction.response.send_message("Type non-negative number of winners!", ephemeral=True)
                else:
                    created_at = datetime.now()
                    duration = parser.parse(duration)
                    duration = duration + round(created_at.timestamp())
                
                    embed = None
                    try:        
                        last_id = self.giveaways.pop()['id']
                        self.id = int(last_id) + 1
                    except:
                        self.id = 1

                    btn = GiveawayButton(self, self.id)

                    giveaway = await self.create_giveaway({
                        'guild_id': interaction.guild.id,
                        'prize': prize,
                        'entries': None,
                        'winners': None,
                        'possible_winners': winners,
                        'duration': str(datetime.fromtimestamp(duration)),
                        'created_at': str(created_at),
                        'ended': False,
                    })

                    giveaway['created_at'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(duration)
                    giveaway['interaction'] = interaction
                    giveaway['entries'] = []
                    giveaway['winners'] = []
                    giveaway['btn'] = btn

                    embed = await self.create_embed(giveaway)
                    giveaway['embed'] = embed

                    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=btn)
                    self.task_launcher(giveaway, 1)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid time format! (1 minutes/1m)", ephemeral=True)
        else:
          await interaction.response.send_message("You don't have permissions to use this.", ephemeral=True)
```

self.create_giveaway sends async request to my dashboard api, it creates the giveaway itself, but doesn't respond with the discord message on the server. Here is the 'create_giveaway' function and the error:

```
async def create_giveaway(self, data):
        endpoint = self.url + "/create-giveaway/"
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(endpoint, json=data) as r:
                if r.status == 200:
                    await self.get_giveaways()
                    return await r.json()
```

[image: Unknown interaction error]

[image: Unknown interaction error 2]

I've tried to create `self.bot.loop.create_task(self.create_giveaway(data))` instead, but this doesn't feel right and I would have to send another API request to get list of giveaways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [3 seconds to respond to an interaction before it is invalidated](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#responding-to-an-interaction).

If your API takes longer than that to respond you will get the 404 error, I suggest [deferring](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) your reply, then responding once your API has returned.

Comment: Actually I could do that, but I found that `self.bot.loop.create_task(self.create_giveaway(data))` does the job too. Problem can appear when api is overloaded tho, I think...